# How to mock an injected class using NSubstitute?

Tags: dependency-injection, structuremap, nsubstitute, structuremap-automocking

I am using StructureMap for my dependency injection. I have the following repository:

```
public class StaffRepository : NHibernateRepository<IStaff>, 
{
    public IEnumerable<IStaff> GetByStaffId(string staffId)
    {
        return Repository.Where(ab => ab.StaffId == staffId);
    }
}
```

I am writing a test to test a method in a controller (ReturnToWorkController):

Which has this repository injected:

```
public ReturnToWorkController(
            IStaffRepository staffRepository)
        {
            this.staffRepository = staffRepository;
        }
```

I am testing my controller (using SpecFlow) by calling the container and resolving it using StructureMap:

```
readonly ReturnToWorkController returnToWorkController;

public SicknessSteps(TestContext testContext)
{
        returnToWorkController = ApplicationContext.Resolve<ReturnToWorkController>();
}
```

then calling the method that I would like to test:

```
returnToWorkController.Approval("x");
```

I am using NSubstitute to mock my repository:

```
var staffRepository = Substitute.For<IStaffRepository>();
            staffRepository.GetByStaffId(currentUserStaffId)
                .Returns(ListStaff.Where(x => x.StaffId == currentUserStaffId));
```

My question is, how can I (or is it even possible) to mock the injected object within the controller? Would this be done in my IoC setup?

Comment: Provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem. Right now the question is still incomplete.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use the container for the test? I realise it is probably a simplified example, but if possible maybe directly create the class under test and substitute for the dependencies you need: `var sub = Substitute.For<IStaffRepository>(); returnToWorkController = new ReturnToWorkController(sub); /* configure sub */`

Comment: can you create the subsitute like so: 
`var staffRepositoryInstance = Substitute.For<IStaffRepository>();` and then register that instance in structure map:
`ApplicationContext.Register<IStaffRepository>(staffRepositoryInstance);`
That way it will inject your controller with a stubbed dependency, without you having to do awkward DI manually